# Connecting to Ubuntu VPS using Windows RDP gives blank screen with Tilix terminal instead of Ubuntu login page?

Tags: login, 22.04, remote-desktop, vps

I am trying to connect to Ubuntu 22.04 on a VPS (OVHcloud) using Windows Remote Desktop Connection. After typing in my login and password, I am presented with this screen Page after Login:

[image]

What I expected was a traditional Ubuntu Login page where I could enter a desktop GUI. I am currently able to control Ubuntu VPS using a terminal (PUTY), but again no ability to use GUI.

I tried several threads on how to troubleshoot, including adding this bit into a document

```
if test -r /etc/profile; then
        . /etc/profile
fi

unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR



test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am currently running Ubuntu on an external hard drive from a Windows computer but would like this option to use a hosted server to free up the Windows computer.

Comment: Maybe I am confused on what I am trying to do. Do Ubuntu Servers have GUIs? I am reading now that I may need to install xfce GUI on Ubuntu server to have "traditional" control.

Comment: By default, no, Ubuntu Server installs have no GUI.  You would have to install one to get a traditional desktop environment GUI

Comment: @user68186 4 vCore, 8GB ,160 SSD NMVe.

Comment: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-a-gui-on-ubuntu This might be what I need.

Comment: You should be able to use the Gnome based Ubuntu desktop. To install it (and xrdp) use the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop xrdp`. If `xrdp` is already installed it will tell you so. Edit your question if get errors.

Comment: To check if you already have any Desktops installed use the command `ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/`.